# How to suppress PHPSESSID in URL for Googlebot?

Tags: google, php, url, search-engine-indexing, clean-urls

I use cookie based sessions, and they work for normal interaction with our site. However, when Googlebot comes crawling our PHP framework, Yii, needs to append `?PHPSESSID` to each URL, which doesn't look that good in SERP.

Any ways to suppress this behavior?

PS. I tried to utilize `ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');`, but it does not work.

PPS. To get an impression of the SERP, they look like this:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=site:wwwdup.uni-leipzig.de+inurl:jobportal

Comment: Looks like Google isn't having any issues at all indexing you. And that session ID won't affect your rankings.

Comment: No, indexing is fine. It just, eeh, doesn't look so good ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using rel="canonical"? This link should help explain, http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394.

Answer (score 3):

See [Webmaster Tools: Updates to Search queries, Parameter handling and Messages](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/10/webmaster-tools-updates-to-search.html) at the Google Webmaster Central blog for instructions to suppress the PHPSESSID parameter in search results.

On the server-side, you should look into a way to prevent every hit from creating a session - session management is expensive server-side and it is generally undesirable to initiate sessions unless the content presented is dependent upon session data (as would hopefully **not** be the case with a search engine crawler).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `CHttpSession::setUseTransparentSessionID(true)` ([api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#setUseTransparentSessionID-detail)) somewhere in your Yii app, if it doesn't already exist.

I don't like visible session IDs either (triggers the flashbacks of PHP3 vs. broken IE cookies), so I always set it.  I'm not 100% sure it'll fix the issue, but I haven't seen any session IDs sneak into search results for the few Yii apps I've built.